# AEM-REX-001-008: Unable to apply the requested usage rights to the given document

Tags: aem, xdp-pdf

We have developed two interactive XDP which have some pre-population and binding of data and they are generated in interactive PDF. Whenever we deploy the XDP in our ETE environment everything is perfect and works fine. We have developed a rest API which generate the PDF and bind values from front end.

The problem is whenever we deploy the XDP in QA environment and try to consume and bind dynamic values to XDP and generate the same PDF documents consuming the same rest API we get failure in generating the documents. I check the error logs of AEM instance and I am getting below. Please can somebody help me out here as we are not able to find what is the root cause of this failure specific to QA Environment.

```
09.07.2019 16:53:13.307 *ERROR* [10.52.160.35 [1562683992994] POST /content/AemFormsSamples/renderpdfform.html HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.fd.readerextensions.service.impl.ReaderExtensionsServiceImpl AEM-REX-001-008: Unable to apply the requested usage rights to the given document.

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

at com.adobe.xfa.form.FormModel.preSave(FormModel.java:7242)

at com.adobe.xfa.form.FormModel.preSave(FormModel.java:7159)

at com.adobe.xfa.form.FormModel.preSave(FormModel.java:7159)

at com.adobe.xfa.form.FormModel.preSave(FormModel.java:7159)

at com.adobe.xfa.form.FormModel.preSave(FormModel.java:7159)

at com.adobe.xfa.form.FormModel.preSave(FormModel.java:7159)
```

Comment: Were you able to find the root cause?